# Gesturedetector: onLongPressStart Details flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to record a video when a button is pressed long (in flutter)

This is my code:

```
GestureDetector(
                    onLongPressStart: () {print("START VIDEO");}
                    onLongPressEnd: () {print("END VIDEO");}
                    onTap: () {print("take photo");},
                    child: Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text("BUTTON"),
                    ),
                  ),
```

But it gives an error:

> ... can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(LongPressEndDetails)'.

What is `LongPressEndDetails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onLongPressStart` requires you to pass `LongPressStartDetails` , so

Instead of

```
onLongPressStart: () {...}
```

use

```
onLongPressStart: (LongPressStartDetails details) {...}
```

or simply

```
onLongPressStart: (details) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it's working...

```
onLongPress: () {
        print('start recording');
    },
    onLongPressUp: () {
        print('stop recording');
    },
```